# How Do I Get Total 1 Time for Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been asked to modify a report (which unfortunately was written horribly!! not by me!) to include a count of days. Please note the "Days" is not calculated using "StartDate" & "EndDate" below. The problem is, there are multiple rows per record (users want to see the detail for start & enddate), so my total for "Days" are counting for each row. How can I get the total 1 time without the total in column repeating?

This is what the data looks like right now:

```
ID          Description     startdate   enddate        Days
REA145681   Emergency       11/17/2011  11/19/2011      49
REA145681   Emergency       12/6/2011   12/9/2011       49
REA145681   Emergency       12/10/2011  12/14/2011      49

REA146425   Emergency       11/23/2011  12/8/2011       54
REA146425   Emergency       12/9/2011   12/12/2011      54
```

I need this:

```
ID          Description     startdate   enddate        Days
REA145681   Emergency       11/17/2011  11/19/2011      49
REA145681   Emergency       12/6/2011   12/9/2011       
REA145681   Emergency       12/10/2011  12/14/2011      

REA146425   Emergency       11/23/2011  12/8/2011       54
REA146425   Emergency       12/9/2011   12/12/2011
```

Help please. This is how the users want to see the data.
Thanks in advance!

Liz

--- Here is the query simplified:

```
    select id
,description
,startdate     -- users want to see all start dates and enddates
,enddate
,days = datediff(d,Isnull(actualstardate,anticipatedstartdate) ,actualenddate) 
    from table
```

Comment: if you post your current query, it'd be easier for us to edit it. Also, please clarify which Database Engine you are using.

Comment: Hi sorry, am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What is the actual table structure? The exiting query that you posted contains columns that don't exist in the data you provided.

Comment: Kevev22 -- table has following fields:  ID, Description, StartDate,EndDate, ActualStartDate, AnticipatedStartDate, ActualEndDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't provide the data of your tables I'll operate over your result as if it was a table. This will result in what you're looking for:

```
select *, 
  case row_number() over (partition by id order by id)
    when 1 then days
  end
from t
```

**Edit:**

Looks like you DID added some SQL code. This should be what you're looking for:

```
select *, 
  case row_number() over (partition by id order by id)
    when 1 then
      datediff(d,Isnull(actualstardate,anticipatedstartdate) ,actualenddate)
  end
from t
```

Comment: Mosty Mostacho!!! THANK YOU!! This worked pefectly!!! Thank you thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That is a task for the reporting tool. You will have to write something like he next code in teh Display Properties of the Days field:

```
if RowNumber > 1 AND id = previous_row(id) 
  then -- hide the value of Days
       Colour = BackgroundColour
       Days = NULL
       Days = ' '
       Display = false
       ... (anything that works)
```

Answer (score 0):

So they want the output to be exactly the same except that they don't want to see the days listed multiple times for each ID value? And they're quite happy to see the ID and Description repeatedly but the Days value annoys them?

That's not really an SQL question. SQL is about which rows, columns and derived values are supposed to be presented in what order and that part seems to be working fine.

Suppressing the redundant occurrences of the Days value is more a matter of using the right tool. I'm not up on the current tools but the last time I was, QMF was very good for this kind of thing. If a column was the basis for a control break, you could, in effect, select an option for that column that told it not to repeat the value of the control break repeatedly. That way, you could keep it from repeating ID, Description AND Days if that's what you wanted. But I don't know if people are still using QMF and I have no idea if you are. And unless the price has come way down, you don't want to go out and buy QMF just to suppress those redundant values.

Other tools might do the same kind of thing but I can't tell you which ones. Perhaps the tool you are using to do your reporting - Crystal Reports or whatever - has that feature. Or not. I think it was called Outlining in QMF but it may have a different name in your tool.

Now, if this report is being generated by an application program, that is a different kettle of Fish. An application could handle that quite nicely. But most people use end-user reporting tools to do this kind of thing to avoid the greater cost involved in writing programs.

We might be able to help further if you specify what tool you are using to generate this report.

Comment: Yes, they want the results exactly like that (which drive me batty because WHY do you need to see the repeating data). I've tried to argue, but no win. I'm using SQL Server 2008 and SSRS for the final ouput. My guess is that they will doing some sort of calculation on the DAYS field, so if they total the field as it is now, they will be definately over counting.